# merge the text view scroll with the screen scroll in ios application

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a view controller which includes three components (label, image and uitextview), in the text view I have my text which has unlimited number of lines.

For this reason, I have used the textview to scroll. But there is a problem, which this text view seems to be like iframe, means its scroll is different to the main scroll of the screen, and I want to merge this scroll with the screen scroll.

[image]

the text view is where (Detail view goes here) is written.
Please help me, 
Thank you,

Comment: So the 3 views you describe are in another scroll view?

Comment: yes, but i don't have a problem with the two above (which i dont need a scroll with the text and image) but the problem with the text which the scroll is needed there.

Comment: So, both scroll views scroll vertically, and you want the full view to scroll if you pan the text view but it has already scrolled to its end?

Comment: Also, is the text in the text view bigger than the size of the text view?

Comment: yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If the text in the text view is smaller than the size of the text view (and always will be), just disable scrolling.

```
scrollEnabled
```

If the text in the text view is bigger than the size of the text view (so you need it to scroll the content text) you can access the pan gesture on the outer scroll view and the text view scroll view to mediate between them. Basically, whenever a new pan starts you would have logic in the pan gesture delegate methods to decide if the text should scroll or if the container view should scroll.